# play framework, redirect block users to some page

Tags: security, playframework, playframework-1.x, spam-prevention

i am using playframework 1.2.5. 
some of the users in my application are making inappropriate actions, like spam etc.

i want to ban thous users from my site. and always show them a page that saying that they are banned.

what is the best option for protecting my self from them that they will not be able to do any action when they are flagged. 
i am using the secure module . will overwriting the Secure class in the secure module 
to handle banned users and show them a specific page sounds like a good solution to you ?

(i can't keep them in the login page , since its a facebook application and i am not using the login page. 
already made some changes to the Secure class to meet my need )

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add a isBanned property set to true for banned users and redirect accordingly.

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    @Before
    static void preAction() {
        if(connectedUser().isBanned){
           banned();
        }
    }


    public static void banned() {
        String title = "You have been naughty";
        render(title);
    }

}
```

And have all your controlled use the @With annotation

```
@With(Application.class)
public class MyControllerextends Controller {
```